# Ruby class never getting into my initialize method after being instantiated

Tags: ruby, methods, initialization

I have the following code. I am having problems getting at the game variables later on in my code, and upon further examination, my initialize code doesn't appear to be getting run. The debugger never fires. Why isn't my initialize method being run here?

```
class Game
  attr_accessor :player, :status

  def initialize
    @player=Player.new
    debugger
    @status="active"
  end

  until @status=="finished" 
    turn=Turn.new
    turn.start_turn
    ...MORE TURN CODE HERE...
  end
end

Game.new
```

Comment: In addition to what @Max said in his answer, after making changes that allow you to run `Game.new`, Ruby will raise a `NoMethod` exception error when it gets to gets to `debugger` (unless you have a method by that name in `class Game` that is not shown in your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike static languages like C++, Ruby actually evaluates the code inside class definitions. Ruby is getting caught in the `until` block, so it never even finishes the class definition to get to the instantiation. You might want to put that code inside a method so that it only runs when you call it later on.

Answer (score 0):

You just got an **infinite loop** with `until @status=="finished"`, the `@status` inside the class definition is `nil`, so `@status=="finished"` will never be `true`.

Run the code below and you will see the infinite loop:

```
class Player; end

class Game
  attr_accessor :player, :status

  def initialize
    @player=Player.new
    @status="active"
  end

  until @status=="finished"
    p 1
  end
end
```